# Max Depth of binary tree with size one

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, depth

I am trying to find the max depth of a binary tree and using the recursive approach. It looks like this:

```
public int depth(TreeNode root) {
    if(root==null) return 0;
    int leftVal=maxDepth(root.left);
    int rightVal=maxDepth(root.right);
    return 1 + Math.max(leftVal,rightVal);
}
```

Now if there is only one node (the root) it will return 1. But isn't the depth of that node 0 with a height of 1 since it is the root? Or does Max Depth of a tree differ from the individual node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth is NOT the measure of tree, but of a node of a tree.

In your case, maxDepth of a node sounds to me like the height of that node.

- The depth of a node is the number of edges from the root to the node.
- The height of a node is the number of edges from the node to the deepest leaf.
- The height of a tree is a height of the root.

Consider this image:

[image: Depth and Height]

Comment: So there is not such thing as a max depth?

Comment: To my understanding, depth of a node is only affected by its parent nodes and above, not nodes below it. So I think, the concept of max depth in your example, is really just the height of a node, which has nothing to do with its depth(consider in the graph, nodes with the same height can have different depth, and vice versa).